# Can I be sure that array.slice() will always work the same as array.slice(0)?

Tags: javascript

I've always used the `.slice()` method with no arguments to make a copy of a JavaScript `Array`. This works fine in every browser and JavaScript environment I've tried: it is treated the same as `.slice(0)`.

It's just a matter of style, but to me omitting the *start* argument entirely makes it more clear that we aren't taking any special sub-slice of the array but want a copy of the whole thing.

However, both [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/tkcsy6fe(v=vs.94).aspx) say that the first argument to `array.slice()` is *required*. Only the second argument is optional. Other online sources such as [TutorialsPoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/array_slice.htm) and [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp) say the same thing. (No, I'm not recommending W3Schools! Just pointing out that they agree with MDN and MSDN on this issue.)

Have I just been lucky with this? Could there be a browser or other JavaScript environment where `array.slice()` doesn't work?

Comment: Not an answer, but maybe relevant: `.slice()` only copies the first dimension of the array; all arrays inside the array are still references.

Comment: @Broxzier - Very good point. The fact that it's a shallow copy needs to be always kept in mind. I have gotten bit badly by that when I've forgotten it! :-) Of course, this would be just as true for `.slice(0)` as it is for `.slice()`.

Answer (score 9):

**All of these online references are mistaken.**

At least if we're talking about standards-complant browsers and runtimes.

The [ECMA-262 standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) requires any conforming implementation to treat `array.slice()` identically to `array.slice(0)`.

Here is how we know this.

First we look at [Section 15.4.4.10](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.10), "Array.prototype.slice (start, end)":

> The `slice` method takes two arguments, *start* and *end*, and returns an array containing the elements of the array from element *start* up to, but not including, element *end* (or through the end of the array if *end* is `undefined`)…

What is this? There's not even any mention of *end* being optional. Are both *start* and *end* required?

Yes, they are. But we need to look elsewhere to understand what this means.

[Section 15](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15), "Standard Built-in ECMAScript Objects" says (in the fourth paragraph):

> Unless otherwise specified in the description of a particular function, if a function or constructor described in this clause is given fewer arguments than the function is specified to require, the function or constructor shall behave exactly as if it had been given sufficient additional arguments, each such argument being the `undefined` value.

And this is consistent with how other methods are specified. We know, for example, that the compare function argument to `array.sort()` is optional, but [Section 15.4.4.11](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.11) "Array.prototype.sort (comparefn)" doesn't say anything about the *comparefn* argument being optional. It just describes what to do when *comparefn* is `undefined` or not.

So now we know that `array.slice()` is interpreted as `array.slice(undefined,undefined)`. Continuing, then, with [Section 15.4.4.10](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.10), we find the relevant step:

> 5 . Let *relativeStart* be ToInteger(*start*).

**ToInteger** is described in [Section 9.4](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.4), where the first two steps are relevant:

> 1 . Let *number* be the result of calling ToNumber on the input argument.
>   2 . If number is `NaN`, return `+0`.

**ToNumber** is found in [Section 9.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3), where the first entry in the table says that when its Argument Type is Undefined, the result is `NaN`.

So, the missing first argument to `array.slice()` is treated as `undefined` and that value is passed into ToNumber, which returns `NaN`. This causes ToInteger to return `0` (or `+0` as they call it here), and that's the value that `array.slice()` uses.

Therefore, `array.slice()` is the same as `array.slice(0)`. If an implementation doesn't treat it that way, it doesn't conform to the ECMA-262 standard.

Of course, that's the standard, and then there is the real world.

If we follow this same analysis for the *second* argument to `.slice()`, we'll come to the conclusion that all of these should work the same (among other similar variations):

```
array.slice()
array.slice( 0 )
array.slice( undefined )
array.slice( 0, undefined )
array.slice( undefined, undefined )
```

However, as @Pumbaa80 points out in a comment, the last two versions do not work in IE8 (nor in IE7)!

But at least the simple `array.slice()` case I was concerned about does work in these old browsers, and should continue to work in any browser or runtime that follows the standard.

Comment: Very nice, but strictly speaking this does not answer your question. Take for example IE8, which (according to MSDN) throws up on `slice(0, undefined)` while there is no problem with `slice(0)`

Comment: @Pumbaa80 - Excellent point! I hadn't noticed that. I updated it a bit to take that into account.

Comment: Thanks. Typo: I meant [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#Streamlining_cross-browser_behavior) there, not MSDN...